# Extracting elements from STArray (similar to unzipping)

Tags: arrays, haskell, unzip, mutable, st-monad

I'm having a slight problem implementing a particle based fluid simulation in Haskell for a programming competition. I currently have an array of particles that gets modified at each simulation step. Each particle is a tuple of 2 vectors: position and velocity (my own Vec3D module). At some point I need to extract the positions from the particles (sort of like unzipping lists) which I tried to do like this:

```
let xs = runSTArray $ do
    xs' <- newArray (min, max) (0.0,0.0,0.0) :: ST s (STArray s Int Vec3D)
    forM_ [min..max] $ \j -> do
        (x, v) <- readArray ps' j
        writeArray xs' j x
    return xs'
let displacements = doubleDensityRelaxation xs restDen k kNear t h
```

where `ps'` and `doubleDensityRelaxation` are of type

```
type Vec3D = (Double, Double, Double)
ps' :: ST s (STArray s Int (Vec3D, Vec3D))
doubleDensityRelaxation :: Array Int Vec3D -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Array Int Vec3D
```

so `xs` should be of type `xs :: Array Int Vec3D`.  However, I get

```
Simulator.hs:76:35:
No instance for (MArray (STArray s) (Vec3D, Vec3D) (ST s1))
  arising from a use of `readArray'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (MArray (STArray s) (Vec3D, Vec3D) (ST s1))
In a stmt of a 'do' block: (x, v) <- readArray ps' j
In the expression:
  do { (x, v) <- readArray ps' j;
       writeArray xs' j x }
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `\ j
     -> do { (x, v) <- readArray ps' j;
             writeArray xs' j x }'
```

from the compiler which I dont really understand given that `readArray` isn't supposed to return an entire array; just one `(Vec3D, Vec3D)` element.

As a fix, could I make `doubleDensityRelaxation` take `ST s (STArray s Int Vec3D)` directly?

If I change the type like that and remove the `let xs = runSTArray $ do` part I get

```
Couldn't match expected type `ST s0 (STArray s0 Int Vec3D)'
            with actual type `STArray s Int Vec3D'
```

but if I give it `(ST s xs')` as an input instead of just `xs'` it complains about data constructor `ST` not being in scope. My imports are currently

```
import Data.List
import Data.Array
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Vec3D
```

Complete function:

```
step :: Array Int (Vec3D, Vec3D) -> Vec3D -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Array Int (Vec3D, Vec3D)
step ps g restDen k kNear t h = runSTArray $ do
    ps' <- thaw ps :: ST s (STArray s Int Particle)
    --GRAVITY
    forM_ [min..max] $ \i -> do
        (x, v) <- readArray ps' i
        writeArray ps' i (x, addGravity v g t)
    --TODO - VISCOSITY
    --MOVE
    xsOld <- newArray (min, max) (0.0,0.0,0.0) :: ST s(STArray s Int Vec3D)
    forM_ [min..max] $ \i -> do
        (x, v) <- readArray ps' i
        writeArray xsOld i x
        writeArray ps' i (x `add` (v `mulSc` t), v)
    --TODO - SPRINGS
    --DOUBLE DENSITY RELAXATION
    xs' <- newArray (min, max) (0.0,0.0,0.0) :: ST s (STArray s Int Vec3D)
    forM_ [min..max] $ \j -> do
        (x, v) <- readArray ps' j
        writeArray xs' j x
    let displacements = doubleDensityRelaxation (freeze xs') restDen k kNear t h
    ps <- newArray (min, max) ((0.0,0.0,0.0), (0.0,0.0,0.0)) :: ST s (STArray s Int (Vec3D, Vec3D))
    --TODO incomplete
    return ps
    where
        addGravity v g t = v `add` (g `mulSc` t)
        (min, max) = bounds ps
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example? The problem is with the type of `ps'` (it should be `STArray s Int (Vec3D, Vec3D)` without the `ST s ...`), but it's hard to give good advice on how to fix it without seeing where `ps'` is coming from.

Comment: @hammar - I see your point. If I take the ST s away though in the very beginning, it gives me this:  
    Simulator.hs:60:21:
        `Couldn't match expected type 'Vec3D' with actual type 'Int'. Expected type: Array Vec3D Vec3D. Actual type: Array Int (Vec3D, Vec3D). In the first argument of 'thaw', namely 'ps'. In a stmt of a 'do' block: ps' <- thaw ps :: STArray s Int Particle`

Comment: Your updated code compiles if I move the freeze call out of the `let displacements = ... line` to `xs'' <- freeze xs'` and then use `xs''` instead of `freeze xs'` ([hpaste](http://hpaste.org/77920)).

Comment: @hammar I get `No instance for (Data.Array.Base.IArray b0 Vec3D)` (the type variable `b0` is ambiguous) without type signature, and getting the correct signature is a tad nontrivial.

Comment: @LemonLord `freeze :: (Ix i, MArray a e m, IArray b e) => a i e -> m (b i e)`. So your `freeze xs'` is an `IArray b Vec3D => ST s (b Int Vec3D)`. To get the actual array, you need to run `freeze` inside the `runSTArray`.

Comment: @hammar: since your comment was the answer, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

community-wiki answer based on the comments:

The updated code compiles if you move the `freeze` call out of the `let displacements = ...` line to `xs'' <- freeze xs'` and then use `xs''` instead of `freeze xs'`

This is because `freeze :: (Ix i, MArray a e m, IArray b e) => a i e -> m (b i e)`. So `freeze xs'` is an `IArray b Vec3D => ST s (b Int Vec3D)`. To get the actual array, you need to run `freeze` inside the `runSTArray`.